# Why does recoding video with FFMPEG on Windows always give an error?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-capture

I downloaded ffmpeg from http://ramiro.arrozcru.org/ffmpeg-vfwcap-noflip.7z
and run it with the command line: `ffmpeg -r 25 -f vfwcap -i 0 output.avi`

but always get the error:

> ffmpeg -r 25 -f vfwcap -i 0 output.avi
>   FFmpeg version SVN-r22915, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
>     built on Apr 20 2010 00:09:08 with gcc 4.4.2
>     configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc=ccach
>   -i686-mingw32-gcc --arch=i686 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
>   --enable-pthreads
>     libavutil     50.14. 0 / 50.14. 0
>     libavcodec    52.66. 0 / 52.66. 0
>     libavformat   52.61. 0 / 52.61. 0
>     libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>     libswscale     0.10. 0 /  0.10. 0
>   [vfwcap @ 012eba60]Could not connect to device.
>   0: Error number -19 occurred

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Was it built with vfwcap? vfw is obsolete and generally disliked so isn't necessarily included

Comment: @alexf The problem might not be with ffmpeg. Do you have a webcam attached to your computer and ready to use? I.e. can you make a video call with skype, for example, or record from the webcam with VLC or some other software?

Comment: @stepan-yakovenko - Please submit a new question with details of what specifically you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try the admin command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`vfwcap` is unable to find your camera, you could try using DirectShow as suggested here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vfwcap.

Documentation and examples are here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow

If you want to keep using `vfwcap`, maybe you could use `list` (https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#vfwcap) to see a list of drivers.